# Incorrectly showing total number of documents in MongoHQ Collection on cloudbees

Tags: cloudbees, mongohq

On Cloudbees MongoHQ , one collection is showing incorrect number as  total number of documents , while other collections are showing correctly  .
When I go inside to that collection and set the limit , it is showing different number as total number of documents .

On the main screen , it is showing 201 documents and getting increased in number , but inside the collection , it is showing only 101 documents , even after set the limit to 201 .

Is there any reason why MongoHQ is showing incorrect total number of documents ?

Comment: Are you stating that the web UI shows a different number of documents in a collection than the MongoDB console is showing?

Comment: It is not a matter of Web UI and console .On web UI main screen , where all collections are getting displayed , one collection is showing 201 documents . When I click on that collection and set the limit to 250 , it is showing 101 documents ...

Comment: Ayush - this may be a case where opening a support ticket would be the best solution - as sounds like a bug to me

Comment: Well it seems that all the collections having more than 100 documents , are showing only 101 documents . Is there any setting to change this or its a bug .

Answer (score 0):

Mongo's default batch size is 101. When you query the database via MongoHQ, the first 101 results are shown, and the rest are hidden. Unfortunately they don't allow you to run the getNext() command.

More here (specific to PHP Mongo drivers): http://derickrethans.nl/cursors-in-mongodb.html